# hide a id in url yii2 using urlManager

Tags: php, yii2

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>'
```

I have written this rule in url manager so that it hide id during update action  i  want the url should be / the id should be hidden. But no luck.
eg:
 I have this url `mysite.com/controller/update/1` i want the url to be `mysite.com/controller/update`

Comment: Do you want to hide it completely or just `id` word? If you mean completely, it's impossible.

Comment: I want to hide only id

Comment: In this case please provide specific example of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You can't do that. Instead encode the id and pass it to update function and decode it there. That would be safe.

Comment: Encode the id? What do you mean by that and why it's needed?

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to achieve is impossible and useless.

Think about it logically. Action in this case simply won't know exactly what model should be loaded and updated.

I see only one possible use case of that.

When you load page `post/update`, then select post from list to update and load it with AJAX.

In this case just remove `id` from action parameters, you don't need to write additional url rules for that.